# Why does my drierite turn bright bright blue, instead of pink?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, water, transition-metals, color

Drierite a brand name of a commonly-used, calcium sulfate-based dessicant in many chemistry labs.  The lab I work in has a dessicator box we use to store hygroscopic materials.  It isn't a a true dry box, just an air-sealed box with a big tray of dessicant at the bottom.  A cheap humidity meter we bought suggests the humidity gets down to 25% or so in there.  We store minute quantities of amine solutions in the box, and some hygroscopic dry materials.

Most drierite pellets are something like pure calcium sulfate, and are therefore a colorless white.  But some pellets are laced with cobalt chloride, a [water-sensitive "indicator" of drierite freshness](https://chlorine.americanchemistry.com/Science-Center/Chlorine-Compound-of-the-Month-Library/Cobalt-Chloride-Colorful-Moisture-Detector/#:%7E:text=Cobalt%20chloride%2C%20CoCl2%2C%20is,blue%20to%20purple%20to%20pink.).  Supposedly, as the drierite absorbs moisture, the cobalt chloride turns from a sky blue into a pinkish color.  When it turns pink you know it's time to change the dessicant to a fresh dry batch.

But our drierite never turns pink.

Instead it turns into a far, far more intense, vivid blue color, much bluer and less pale than indicator drierite starts out as.  (See photo of too-blue drierite in tray, with a bottle of fresh starting indicator drierite at left.)

[image: New and old indicator drierite]

*Why doesn't my drierite turn pink?*. Why does it turn this shade of blue?  Presumably some other kind of complex or hydrate rather than the classic cobalt chloride hexahydrate is forming.  Is it an issue of pH?  Or of some volatile organic being adsorbed?

Comment: I have seen similar behavior of Drierite of acquiring a deeper blue color instead of the expected pink color in dessicators. Most likely your amines have significant vapor pressure. If you recall most amine complexes of cobalt are really deep blue like the Schweizer's reagent. You can try adding a drop of a couple of test amines in separate cobalt chloride solutions and see what happens.

Comment: OT why do you store the amine solutions in that box. Just because you manipulate them therein?

Comment: @M.Farooq Why not an answer?

Comment: @Alchimista, Because I want the OP to update the readers if his amines actually turn cobalt chloride solution blue. If they don't then this conjecture might be wrong.

Comment: They are amine solutions in DMSO, not water.  Some of the time, we use them in chemical reactions where water is detrimental.

Comment: But amines must have some vapor pressure in DMSO. This over-bluing effect takes month(s) and it is not instantaneous.

Comment: Support of M. Farooq's theory: in addition to the Drierite I put in some silica-supported P2O5, and now the Drierite does not turn this color of blue.  I guess the amine is much more preferentially attracted to the acid anhydride P2O5?